# Difficult Dataframe Reshape in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         DATE1    DATE2   DATE3   AMOUNT1   AMOUNT2   AMOUNT3

1        1/1/15   5/22/14 7/12/13    5        6         3
..         ..       ..       ..      ..       ..        ..
```

and I want to get it in the form:

```
    DATE  AMOUNT
1  1/1/15   5
2  5/22/14  6
3  7/12/13  3
..   ..     ..
```

What is the most efficient code to do this?  From what I can tel melting or grouping wont work because of the difference in column names (DATE1, DATE2, etc).  Is the best thing to subset the "1" columns, "2" columns, and "3" columns into smaller dataframes, rename the columns, and concat?  Or is there a better way to do it that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `pd.lreshape`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/15', '5/22/14', '7/12/13', 5, 6, 3]], 
                  columns=['DATE1', 'DATE2', 'DATE3', 'AMOUNT1', 'AMOUNT2', 'AMOUNT3'])

result = pd.lreshape(df, {'AMOUNT': ['AMOUNT1', 'AMOUNT2', 'AMOUNT3'],
                          'DATE': ['DATE1', 'DATE2', 'DATE3']})
print(result)
```

yields

```
      DATE  AMOUNT
0   1/1/15       5
1  5/22/14       6
2  7/12/13       3
```

The second argument to `pd.lreshape` is a dict of key/value pairs. Each key is
the name of a desired column, and each value is a list of columns from `df`
which you wish to coalesce into one column.

See the docstring, `help(pd.lreshape)`, for a little more on `pd.lreshape`.

---

Alternatively, you could use `pd.melt` to coalesce all the columns into one column, and use `str.extract` to separate the text-part from the numeric-part of the column names. Then use `pivot` to obtain the desired result:

```
result = pd.melt(df)
result[['variable', 'num']] = result['variable'].str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)', expand=True)
result = result.pivot(index='num', columns='variable', values='value')
print(result)
```

yields

```
variable AMOUNT     DATE
num                     
1             5   1/1/15
2             6  5/22/14
3             3  7/12/13
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could you please explain the code in reshape()?

Comment: Thank you! Very clear and helpful.  Is there a good resource for finding these sort of "obscure" methods?  Not only was I unfamiliar with lreshape() - I wouldn't even know where to look to find a method like that.

Comment: I found `lreshape` by using [IPython's tab-completion](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/tutorial.html#tab-completion) feature. It is very useful for familiarizing yourself with objects and finding out what methods are available.

Answer (score 5):

Just reshape the `.values`

```
In [213]:

print df

    DATE1    DATE2    DATE3  AMOUNT1  AMOUNT2  AMOUNT3
1  1/1/15  5/22/14  7/12/13        5        6        3

In [214]:

print pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape((-1, 2), order='F'),
                   columns=['DATE', 'AMOUNT'])

      DATE AMOUNT
0   1/1/15      5
1  5/22/14      6
2  7/12/13      3
```

Assuming each row always has N dates and N amounts (which should be the case?), we could just reshape the values of the original dataframe to a dataframe of dimension of 2 columns. We don't know how many rows we will end up with, that's why we could use the `(-1, 2)` shape in the `.reshape` call and let `.reshape` to determine how many rows are needed.  `F` means `FORTRAN` order, which is row-major, effectively it is the same as `pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape((-1, 2)).T`

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please explain the code inside reshape()?

Comment: Thanks.  what is the (-1,2) shape?  I'm surmising that 2 is columns - if that is the case what is -1 for rows?  Sorry if that is a dumb question

Comment: In reshape, one of the parameter in `reshape` can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's yet another approach: you can `groupby` on the columns.

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby(df.columns.str[:-1], axis=1, sort=False)
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_items((k, v.values.ravel()) for k,v in grouped)
      DATE  AMOUNT
0   1/1/15       5
1  5/22/14       6
2  7/12/13       3
```

Removing only the last character isn't as robust as using `df.columns.str.extract("([A-Z]*)"` or something, but for demonstration purposes it'll work.